# Loop Through Dates on First Row and match if on first row of other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to find cell value with *2021* in Sheet1 Row1, then if that cell value is not found in Sheet2("Monthly2") Row1 then paste that date in the next available cell. For some reason, this code currently finds the last cell with *2021* in Sheet1 and only pastes it into Sheets("Monthly2") Cell A1.

```
Sub Monthly2()

Dim Monthly2 As Worksheet
Dim celldate As Range, MatchingDate As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set rng1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AD1")
Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Monthly2").Range("A1:AD1")


For Each celldate In rng1

    If celldate Like "*2021*" Then   
    
            For Each MatchingDate In rng2
                        
            If celldate = MatchingDate Then            
                                  
            ElseIf celldate <> MatchingDate Then                      
                       
            Sheets("Monthly2").Range("A1:AD1").Value = celldate
                        
            End If
           
            Next MatchingDate
    
        End If         
    
Next celldate

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to do? That code as is won't work, you can't compare values like that. If you want to find a specific value in a range look at using Application.Match or Find.

Comment: What should happen if the date is **not** found ?

Comment: If date isn't found the rest of my code will input values and formatting. That part I've already got taken care of. I'm trying to automate some of the code rather than compiling each date one at a time.

Comment: @CorrieByrd Don't post code in comments, if it's relevant to the question edit the question and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

why not try to compare the value vs the minimun double value to appertain to 2021

Ex. the date:Jan 1, 2021 is 44197.00 as double value

if you compare your cell>= 44197 then is 2021 at least

also you can add the end of the year 44561.00 as double value

```
Const YearBegin = 44197, YearEnds = 44561

Sub IterareDates()
    For Each CellDate In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AD1")
        'this if, indicate that value appertain to 2021
        If CellDate.Value >= YearBegin And CellDate.Value <= YearEnds Then
            'I dont understand those lines, I suppose you are trying to compare cell
            'by cell in 2 sheets, if im right, you are comparing 2 entire ranges,
            'you should compare each cell separately or sum values and if diferent set         which you need

            If ThisWorkbook.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:AD1"),  CellDate.Value) > 0 Then
                'exist
            Else
                'dont
            End If


        End If
    Next CellDate
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to compare cell values in 2 different sheets. And if a date is located in Sheet2 that was from Sheet1, then loop to next date.

Comment: okok, if you need to know if the range contain that date, just add a countIf like in the answer, i edited

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```vb
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim rng1 as Range, rng2 as Range
Dim rng as Range, celldate as Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set rng1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AD1")
Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Monthly").Range("A1:AD1")

For Each celldate In rng1
    If celldate Like "*2021*" Then
        Set rng = rng2.Find(celldate)
        If rng is Nothing Then
           ' not found
        Else
           ' found do something
        Endif
    End If
Next
```